# How to extract version from tnsping output in AIX, SunOS, Linux and HP-UX

Tags: linux, aix, hp-ux, sunos

I want to fetch `10.2.0.4.0` from tnsping output in AIX, so I wrote `tnsping tucson | grep Version | awk '{print $9}'`, but sometimes in other platforms like Linux the column varies, so I cannot use `{print $9}` everywhere. Is there a way such that

1. The command looks for `Version`
2. and then just after it prints whatever number comes up (including ".")

Or any other methods?

```
TNS Ping Utility for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on 16-NOV-2011 16:19:02

Copyright (c) 1997,  2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:

Used HOSTNAME adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=bluebird.informatica.com))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.65.40.235)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out
```

I got it for AIX, HPUX, and Linux:

```
tnsping tucson | grep Version | awk -F Version  '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

But I get an error on **SunOS** I want something that will work on Linux, HP-UX, AIX, and SunOS.

```
zenvo%  tnsping tucson | grep Version | awk -F Version  '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
```

**Update after Shelter's answer**

Linux, AIX and HP-UX:

```
tnsping tucson | grep Version | awk -F Version  '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

SunOS:

```
tnsping tucson | grep Version | nawk -F Version  '{print $2}' | nawk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWK on Solaris is old AWK. Usually, Solaris people use nawk to get the benefits of 'new' AWK.

I don't think old AWK supports a multi-character value as a field separator as you defined `-F Version` (nice trick!). If you're lucky, add quotes around that value might solve the problem.

More likely, you have to make your script smart to assign nawk when running on Solaris.

Something like

```
case $( uname -a ) in
    *Solaris* ) awk=nawk ;;
    * ) awk=awk
esac

tnsping tucson | grep Version | ${awk} -F "Version"  '{print $2}' | ${awk} '{print $1}'
```

should do the trick. I don't have access to a Solaris system anymore, so I can't verify that this will work, but I'd be surprised if it doesn't.

Hmm, now something from my past tells me that even nawk on Solaris didn't like strings as FieldSeps. Maybe you can get awksome gawk installed OR another solution (it seems you're on the way there), just

```
tnsping tucson | ${awk} '/Version/ {sub(/,*Version /, "", $0) ; sub(/.*$/, "", $0); print $0; exit}'
```

and you should be whittled down to your version number anyway. Also, with the filter in AWK for '/Version/', you don't need the grep in between AND we've eliminated an extra call to AWK.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @shelter: thanks for letting me know about `nawk` My `AIX` system is currently down, and nawk gives me the version # in solaris

Answer (score 1):

Please try with **[sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)**:

```
tnsping tucson |
sed -n '/Version/{                                                       # Grep like
    s@.* Version \([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\).*@\1@i  # Substitution with @ separator
    p;                                                                   # Print
    q;                                                                   # quit
}'
```